# create url in yii2 console

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm dealing with the problem of creating the url in yii2 console app. 
Here is my config in console.php :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'scriptUrl' => 'https://sesmailer.net',
        'rules' => [
            'api/unsubscribe/<param:\w+>' => 'api/web/unsubscribe'
        ]
    ],
```

But when I tried to create a pretty url in console using this line of code

```
Url::to([
        "api/web/unsubscribe",
        'param' => base64_encode(serialize($params))
    ]);
```

It creates a url like example.com/api/web/unsubscribe?param=aTo4NjAwOw%3D%3D

Any solutions to create a url like example.com/api/unsubscribe/aTo4NjAwOw%3D%3D

Comment: there is no need to add it to rules and just use api/unsubscribe as first param when you create a link ?

Comment: If you don't add it to rules, how can it create a pretty url. Just notice there is no string "param=" in the pretty url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by editing the regex expression. it was wrong and could not recognize the  base64 string.